# Selected BarButtonItem not showing.

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibarbuttonitem, selected

Whenever the user selects the `UIViewController` the selected `BarButtonItem` disappears. In apple's documentation it recommends using two separate images for the selected state, and the unselected state. I do this, but the the selected image does not show up. In the console I get the following code. How can I make it so that when the selected image shows up.
 
`2015-01-03 10:55:22.718 Grouper[2105:130730] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:           (null)
2015-01-03 10:55:22.718 Grouper[2105:130730] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
2015-01-03 10:55:22.718 Grouper[2105:130730] Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "SR.Grouper"`
If the answer involves code, please use swift, as I am not very familiar with objective-c.

[image]

Comment: Delete existing image & add again , make sure while adding image ur checking checkBox copy item if needed . Check once image exist in your assets or not ?

Comment: @KrunalDarji what do you mean to "Check once image exist in your assets or not"?

Comment: There is a folder in your Xcode project called "Images.xcassets". Make sure you put your image files in that folder.

Comment: @narner I have put the images in the   "Images.xcassets" folder